# Pattern prediction using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am a newbie to Genetic Algorithm. I am trying to predict the pattern of occurrences of rules. For example, I have a set of rules defined as below.

Rule 1,
Rule 2,
Rule 3,
Rule 4,
Rule 5,
Rule 6,

For a given date, I could have only Rule 2, Rule 3 and Rule 6 are used. So I would represent this data as a string as stated below

0 1 1 0 0 1

where 1 denotes that the rule is used and 0 denotes that the rule never get used on that day.

So I would have set of data for 5 days as below

011001,
100010,
110011,
101010,
111100,

What I would like to achieve here is to predict the the 6th day data. I have been reading about Genetic Algorithm and Back propagation method to achieve this. I am failed to map my problem with GA or BP due to lack of understanding about those concepts.

I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction to help me to map my problem with either GA or BP. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what kind of structure are you suspecting under the occurrence of rules? without some assumption it's kind of hard to reward anything but good guessing

Comment: The occurrences of rules are purely random. What I am trying to do here is identify non random pattern among random data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The occurrences of rules are purely
>   random

In that case there's no way to predict them I am afraid!

In case the above is not accurate (rule occurrence is not purely random), do you have a training set? How big is it? You should be looking at pattern recognition techniques here more than GAs.

For example recurrent networks seem to be a good fit for your problem. Have a look at [this paper](http://asmedl.aip.org/ebooks/asme/asme_press/802566/802566_paper116), they predict binary time series instead of binary strings but its as close as it gets!

Another approach that comes to mind could be to combine neural networks + GAs in a fashion similar to the way they're doing it on [this paper here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=672809) for financial prediction.

But I am guessing you need a much bigger training set either way, and you'll have to adapt it to your case.

Beware: this is not a trivial task!

Comment: Thanks John. I have around 1000 historical data.  If I were to look at pattern recognition, do you think back propagation would be a considerable approach?  Or is there anything else I should start looking at specifically?

Answer (score 0):

GA's are more suited for optimization problems than prediction. If you are interested in using GA's however, you could use it to optimize the parameters for a Neural Network which could be used to predict a pattern. Another useful thing to look at is machine learning using linear regression. With linear regression a regression line can be used as an estimator for predicting the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your rule set by using GA and then provide the optimize set as input to Neural network for prediction, I am afraid you cannot use GA for prediction, prediction required a Inference rules or a well formed training data as input to NN(past information).