# How to use genetic algorithm for prediction correctly

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to use genetic algorithm for classification problem. However, I didn't succeed to get a summary for the model nor a prediction for a new data frame. How can I get the summary and the prediction for the new dataset?
Here is my toy example:

```
library(genalg)
dat <- read.table(text = " cats birds    wolfs     snakes
                  0        3        9         7
                  1        3        8         7
                  1        1        2         3
                  0        1        2         3
                  0        1        2         3
                  1        6        1         1
                  0        6        1         1
                  1        6        1         1   ", header = TRUE) 
evalFunc <- function(x) {
        if (dat$cats < 1) 
        return(0) else return(1)
}
iter = 100
GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size = 7, popSize = 200, iters = iter, mutationChance = 0.01, 
                    elitism = T, evalFunc = evalFunc)

###########summary try#############

cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel))
# Error in cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel)) : 
#   could not find function "summary.rbga"

############# prediction try###########

dat$pred<-predict(GAmodel,newdata=dat)
# Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
#   no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "rbga"
```

Update:
After reading the answer given and reading this link:
[Pattern prediction using Genetic Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905477/pattern-prediction-using-genetic-algorithm?rq=1)
I wonder how can I programmatically use the GA as part of a prediction mechanism? According to the link's text, one can use the GA for optimizing regression or NN and then use the predict function provided by them/

Comment: For your first question: `cat(summary(GAmodel))` should work. But what you're trying to do is unclear, could you provide more context?

Comment: And what is `evalFunc` supposed to do? It doesn't use `x`...

Comment: The Idea is to use the algorithm for classification problem.I'm not familiar with this kind of algorithms so I guessed that the evalFunc is for defining the optimization problem - distinguish between "0" and "1".

Answer (score 4):

[Genetic Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)  are for optimization,  not for classification. Therefore, there *is* no prediction method.  Your summary statement was close to working.

```
cat(summary(GAmodel))
GA Settings
  Type                  = binary chromosome
  Population size       = 200
  Number of Generations = 100
  Elitism               = TRUE
  Mutation Chance       = 0.01

Search Domain
  Var 1 = [,]
  Var 0 = [,]

GA Results
  Best Solution : 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Some additional information is available from [Imperial College London](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_96/journal/vol1/hmw/article1.html#introduction)

**Update** in response to updated question:

I see from the paper that you mentioned how this makes sense. The idea is to use the genetic algorithm to optimize the weights for a neural network, then use the neural network for classification. This would be a big task, too big to respond here.

Comment: Thank you for your help @G5W, I've updated my question as I'm looking for a prediction solution as described in the provided link.